# Sphinx autodoc and multi-line strings

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a python module which defines a multi-line string constant. I want to have the multi-line string display nicely in the Sphinx-based documentation.

Below, is some example Python code, RST, and how it renders with `sphinx-build`. However, I would rather get something like the "desired sphinx docs".

Is this possible?

**mymodule.py**

```
#: Default configuration
DEFAULT_CONFIG = r"""
{ "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "rex" }
"""
```

**mydocs.rst**

```
...

--------------
Default Config
--------------

.. autodata:: mymodule.DEFAULT_CONFIG
```

**Resulting Sphinx Docs**

```
mymodule.DEFAULT_CONFIG
= "{ \"foo\": \"bar\",\n  \"bar\": \"rex\" }"

str(object=’‘) -> str str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str

Create a new string object from the given object.
If encoding or errors is specified, then the object
must expose a data buffer that will be decoded using
the given encoding and error handler. Otherwise, returns
the result of object.__str__() (if defined) or repr(object).
encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding(). errors defaults to ‘strict’.
```

**Desired Sphinx Docs**

```
mymodule.DEFAULT_CONFIG = Default configuration
{ "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "rex" }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be supported directly, but since you're using Sphinx and Python the following hack is what I decided to go with:

1. In this example, it is important that you can `import` the variable you desire.  This should already be working, since `autodoc` is able to produce output.
2. This hack will enable you to have a more human friendly output, **but** you will **also** still have the value of the variable (as far as sphinx is concerned) in the undesireable (with a bunch of `\n` characters).

I will be reusing my own project for this, but using your variable / value.  My package name is `exhale` and the file I'm putting this in is `exhale/configs.py`, so that's where that stuff is coming from.  So this is the layout:

#### File: `exhale/configs.py`

This is your actual python code.  It looks like this:

```
__name__ = "configs"
__docformat__ = "reStructuredText"

DEFAULT_CONFIG = r"""
{ "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "rex" }
"""
'''
This is some description of the use of / intended purpose of the variable.

The contents of this variable are a multi-line string with value:

.. include:: DEFAULT_CONFIG_value.rst

.. note::

   The above value is presented for readability, take special care in use of
   this variable that the real value has both a leading and trailing ``\\n``.
'''
```

#### In your sphinx documentation

In whatever file you had the `autodata` above (I used `automodule`, it doesn't matter).  The docs look like this (to be clear, you've already got this, and **do not need to change it**).  The things you need to change are your actual python docstring, and the next section.  This is here for completeness of the answer.

```
Exhale Configs Module
=====================

.. automodule:: exhale.configs
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
```

#### Modify your `conf.py`

This is the fancy part, and a huge benefit to using Sphinx -- Python is so freaking convenient when it comes to writing files.  In the above docstring, you'll see that I deliberately have a `.. include` directive.  The crazy part about this is we can write this file dynamically.  At the bottom of your `conf.py`, you can just add something like

```
# Import the variable from wherever it lives
from exhale.configs import DEFAULT_CONFIG
default_parts = DEFAULT_CONFIG.strip().splitlines()
# Because I am deliberately putting this underneath a '.. code-block:: py',
# we need to indent by **THREE** spaces.
#
# Similarly, when writing to the file, the "\n\n   " before
# {default_config_value} (the three spaces) is also important ;)
default_config_value = "\n   ".join(p for p in default_parts)
with open("DEFAULT_CONFIG_value.rst", "w") as dcv:
    dcv.write(".. code-block:: py\n\n   {default_config_value}\n\n".format(
        default_config_value=default_config_value
    ))
```

If you are using Python **3**, instead of splitting and joining, just use [`textwrap.indent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.indent).  I did the above just to make sure Python 2 users can replicate.

#### KABOOM

When you run `make html`, it will regenerate the file `DEFAULT_CONFIG_value.rst` every time!  So even if you change the value of the variable, it should be good to go.  For reference, the generated file for me looks like this

```
.. code-block:: py

   { "foo": "bar",
     "baz": "rex" }
```

**Note**: this is not a standalone reStructuredText document, it should only every be used via `.. include::`!

Last but not least, the rendered output looks like this:

[image: sphinx generated docs]

As stated in the preamble, Sphinx **is** going to include the `\n` version in the value.  We are just putting this in the docstring.  It's very useful to have **both**.  The reason is because with the `.. code-block:: py` approach, Sphinx will strip leading / trailing newlines (hence the `.. note::` in the docstring).  So it is very helpful to have the human-readable version, but it's also useful to know the raw value.

The only other thing worth mentioning here is that the sky is the limit!  I chose to use `.. code-block:: py` for my purposes, but since you're literally writing the file yourself you can do whatever you want.  You could write the file so that it instead produces

```
.. code-block:: py

   DEFAULT_CONFIG = r"""
   { "foo": "bar",
     "baz": "rex" }
   """
```

by changing the part in `conf.py`.  It's up to you!  When changing the output you may get bugs, open up the generated `.rst` document and make sure it's valid :)